# How to write a util function that takes map as an input iterate over all the keys and calls this function and returns a sanitized key value map?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

This is the function addorUpdateAddress instead of using this sanitizeXSS and decrypt_key again and again write a util function that takes map as an input iterate over all the keys and calls this function and returns a sanitized key value map.

```
addOrUpdateAddress : function (request, resolve) 
    {
        const customerKey = sanitizeXSS(decrypt_key(request.customer_key));
        const lat = sanitizeXSS(decrypt_key(request.lat));
        const lng = sanitizeXSS(decrypt_key(request.lng));
        const line1 = sanitizeXSS(decrypt_key(request.line1));
        const line2 = sanitizeXSS(decrypt_key(request.line2));
        const city = sanitizeXSS(decrypt_key(request.city));
        const pincode = sanitizeXSS(decrypt_key(request.pincode));
        const state = sanitizeXSS(decrypt_key(request.state));
       
        const contact = sanitizeXSS(decrypt_key(request.contact));
        const landmark = request.landmark?sanitizeXSS(decrypt_key(request.landmark)):null;     
     }
 sanitizeXSS: string => {
      const map = {
          '&': '&amp;',
          '<': '&lt;',
          '>': '&gt;',
          '"': '&quot;',
          "'": '&#x27;',
          "/": '&#x2F;',
      };
      const reg = /[&<>"'/]/ig;
      return string.replace(reg, (match)=>(map[match]));
    }
function decrypt_key(message, action)
{
    var text = message;
    var encrypted = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var ASCII = text[i].charCodeAt(0);
    var n = null;

    if(i % 2 == 0) {
      n = action == 'encrypt' ? ASCII + 4 : ASCII - 4;
    }

    else if(i % 2 == 1) {
      n = action == 'encrypt' ? ASCII + 3 : ASCII - 3;
    }

    var s = String.fromCharCode(n);

        encrypted += s;
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write such function.

```
function sanitizeXSS(string){
      const map = {
          '&': '&amp;',
          '<': '&lt;',
          '>': '&gt;',
          '"': '&quot;',
          "'": '&#x27;',
          "/": '&#x2F;',
      };
      const reg = /[&<>"'/]/ig;
      return string.replace(reg, (match)=>(map[match]));
}

function decrypt_key(message, action)
{
    var text = message;
    var encrypted = "";

    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var ASCII = text[i].charCodeAt(0);
    var n = null;

    if(i % 2 == 0) {
      n = action == 'encrypt' ? ASCII + 4 : ASCII - 4;
    }

    else if(i % 2 == 1) {
      n = action == 'encrypt' ? ASCII + 3 : ASCII - 3;
    }

    var s = String.fromCharCode(n);

        encrypted += s;
    }
    return encrypted;
}

function decryptAndSanitizeXss(obj){
  let newObj = {}
  for(const prop in obj)    {
    if(obj[prop]){
        newObj[prop] = sanitizeXSS(decrypt_key(obj[prop]));    
    }
    }
    return newObj
}

function addOrUpdateAddress(request, resolve) {
   request = decryptAndSanitizeXss(request)
}
```

Comment: Can u please write what should be their in prop, obj in your decryptAndSanitizeXss function?

Comment: And also in addorUpdateAddress function how it is ensuring that all those query params will be passed here?

Comment: @neha For your first comment, please refer function call to decryptAndSanitizeXss, provided as last line. Here, decryptAndSanitizeXss function reads property from object which is passed  to the function and update it into the other object.
As an backup, you can also create clone of your original map and update properties into clone directly.